# Vim reseting to foldmethod=manual once navigating buffers

Tags: vimrc, folding

I have created a `ftplugin/html.vim` file with a custom fold expression.

On my `.vimrc` file I have the following:

```
set foldmethod=syntax "all files use syntax fold method
autocmd Syntax html set foldmethod=expr foldexpr=HTMLFolds() "html files use custom fold method
```

However when opening an `index.html` and then another file, let's say `app.js` and then toggling between the files with `bp` and `bn`.

The fold method is never kept and somehow reset to `manual`

Is there any way to keep the foldmethod for each buffer when navigating files in vim so the `foldmethod` is kept always the one it should be?

#### behaviour example

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Can you check all the times that the `Syntax` event is being called ? [This might help you](https://gist.github.com/nobe4/aa8313fe98ca8821afad). You could have an insight of why the syntax is reset ...

Comment: strange, when using your the example file as my `.vimrc` look what happened when trying to edit `index.html` file. https://asciinema.org/a/ej8meo7k8bcgpyeiifbbhnv0k

Comment: never happened to me before, did you try just sourcing the file with your normal vimrc?

Comment: @Nobe4 weird, isn't it? I have also appended the code provided to my `.vimrc` file, but it had the same result I'm afraid. :( Perhaps my vim installation is broken? I simply installed on mac through `brew install vim`

Comment: This is indeed strange. Have you tried without your vimrc, and only with the debug script as your vimrc file ? `vim -u log.vim -N`

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have `ftplugin/html.vim` you should simply add these lines to it and keep your `vimrc` clean:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=HTMLFolds()
```

Also, you should probably make `HTMLFolds()` local to your script:

```
function! s:HTMLFolds()
    ...
function
```

and call it like that:

```
setlocal foldexpr=s:HTMLFolds()
```

Comment: weird, if I add the `s:` flag to the method name and `foldexpr` call as suggested the folds are not created anymore?